# manipulating content with ng-bind-html and default content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use angular to reload (or 'livechange') content - the content default structure isn't created by angular.
so i have the following

```
<div>Default Value</div>
```

and i want to be able to rebuild the content with angular (ng-bind-html is a great solution, but it cant use 'default' value).

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using ng-hide/ng-show directive please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/oHJMD6UU3xOOg5HZo3IC?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <textarea name="comment" ng-model="myHTML"></textarea>
  <div ng-bind-html="myHTML" ng-show="myHTML"></div>
  <div ng-hide="myHTML">Default Value</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't want to do manipulation that way. my main idea is to leave the html as is and make the manipulation through angular. what i did at the end is using $event.target.innerHTML